# tgbot-cpp - Answer inline query

Tags: c++

How to answer inline queries using [tgbot-cpp](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp) ? I've tried a couple of things but none of them worked..

The last thing I tried trowed me this error: `Bad Request: can't parse json encoded inline query results: Unexpected string end`

```
bot.getEvents().onInlineQuery([&bot](const TgBot::InlineQuery::Ptr& query) {

    std::vector<TgBot::InlineQueryResult::Ptr> results;
    TgBot::InlineQueryResultArticle::Ptr article(new TgBot::InlineQueryResultArticle);

    auto text = TgBot::InputTextMessageContent();
    text.messageText = "Inline Test";

    article->title = "Inline Title!";
    article->id = "1234";
    results.push_back(article);

    bot.getApi().answerInlineQuery(query->id, results);});
```

Comment: might be relevant https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp/issues/113

Comment: Yes, it was. Thanks :)